# details of async/await in typescript

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, typescript

I have read various introduction texts about the topic but I still struggle with the details (in nodejs).

```
async function a() {
    const e = await Promise.resolve(42);
    console.log(e);
    return e;
}
const b = a();
console.log(b);
```

displays

```
Promise { <pending> }
42
```

What is explanation for b and e not being the same? After removing await I am getting

```
Promise { 42 }
Promise { <pending> }
```

Again not the same. Replacing the right side of e initialization by the plain number 42 gives me a another promise for b

```
42
Promise { 42 }
```

Can you explain it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because its *async*!

You think that `e` is printing before `b`. But that is not the case. `b` is pointing to the final promise of calling `a` (hence `b` `Promise`). While `a` executes `e` only comes out from `yield` result ( `e = await somPromise`). So `e` points to the resolved value.

The following is helpful :

```
async function a() {
    const e = await Promise.resolve(42);
    console.log('e',e);
    return e;
}
const b = a();
console.log('b',b);
```

which prints

```
b Promise { <pending> }
e 42
```

## More

some docs https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/async-await.html

Answer (score 0):

The `async` function pauses when it finds `await`, while the code outside it continues.

In short when `console.log(b)` is executed, the async function has not yet resolved so you get the `<pending>` state. In the next `tick` the promise resolves, the async function continues you get the 42 in there.

In your last part, `await` doesn't pause the function because there's no promise, so you get the 42 right away.

Answer (score 0):

A *practical* way to look at it is that inside an `async` function, after an `await`, your are in a `then` i.e.

```
async function a(): Promise<number> {
    const e = await Promise.resolve(42);
    //now "in a then"
    console.log('e',e);
    return e;
}
```

is somewhat (`await` waits) equivalent to

```
function a(): Promise<number> {
    return Promise.resolve(42)
      //now "in a then"
      .then(e => {
        console.log('e',e);
        return e;
      })
}
```